# Explanation on dup syscall

Tags: c, linux, unix

```
  close(fileno(stdout));

  int fd = dup(fileno(stdin));
  //printf("Hello World\n");
  write(fd, "Hello", 7);
```

Here for both printf and write is writing Hello to the screen..But I think they should not because I am duplicating the `stdin` to 1 or `stdout` closed perviously. And `printf` is connected to `stdout` but not `stdin` but still they are printing...Please explain if I have anything wrong in understanding the dup

Comment: Can you tell us the output of `cat /proc/self/fdinfo/0`  ? Your system is probably conveniently opening stdin and stdout each for both reading and writing.

Comment: maybe this link would be a good starting point to explain what is happening: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial

Comment: @MarkPlotnick no such file in the directory...see the caf's answer...can you comment on it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `printf` and `write` in your code happen to work, due to historical custom. Here's what's happening:

When a user logs into a terminal on a Unix-like system, or opens a terminal window under X11, file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 are connected to a terminal device, and each of them is opened for **both reading and writing**. This is the case **despite the fact that one normally only reads from fd 0 and writes to fd 1 and 2**.

Yet here is the code from [7th edition init.c](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/init.c):

```
open(tty, 2);
dup(0);
dup(0);
...
execl(getty, minus, tty, (char *)0);
```

And here is how `ssh` does it:

```
ioctl(*ttyfd, TCSETCTTY, NULL);
fd = open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR);
if (fd < 0)
    error("%.100s: %.100s", tty, strerror(errno));
close(*ttyfd);
*ttyfd = fd;
...
/* Redirect stdin/stdout/stderr from the pseudo tty. */
if (dup2(ttyfd, 0) < 0) 
    error("dup2 stdin: %s", strerror(errno));
if (dup2(ttyfd, 1) < 0) 
    error("dup2 stdout: %s", strerror(errno));
if (dup2(ttyfd, 2) < 0) 
    error("dup2 stderr: %s", strerror(errno));
```

(The `dup2` function dups arg1 into arg2, closing arg2 first if necessary.)

And here is how `xterm` does it:

```
if ((ttyfd = open(ttydev, O_RDWR)) >= 0) {
    /* make /dev/tty work */
    ioctl(ttyfd, TCSETCTTY, 0);
...
/* this is the time to go and set up stdin, out, and err
 */
{
/* dup the tty */
for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    if (i != ttyfd) {
    IGNORE_RC(close(i));
    IGNORE_RC(dup(ttyfd));
    }
/* and close the tty */
if (ttyfd > 2)
    close_fd(ttyfd);
```

Back to your code.

```
close(fileno(stdout));
```

This closes fd 1.

```
int fd = dup(fileno(stdin));
```

This duplicates fd 0 into the lowest available fd, which is 1, and assigns 1 to `fd`. (This assumes that fd 0 is open, of course.) Both fd's 0 and 1 are now open for reading and writing (assuming they're connected to a terminal device). On a Linux system you can verify this:

```
$ cat /proc/self/fdinfo/0
pos:    0
flags:  0100002
mnt_id: 20
$ cat /proc/self/fdinfo/1
pos:    0
flags:  0100002
mnt_id: 20
```

The `2` in `flags`, which is the constant `O_RDWR`, means open for reading and writing.

```
printf("Hello World\n");
```

This writes to fd 1, which is, once again, open for reading and writing to your terminal.

```
write(fd, "Hello", 7);
```

This writes to fd 1 again. (Note that `"Hello"` is only 6 bytes, though.)

Answer (score 4):

If you are running your program on a terminal, then `stdin` and `stdout` are opens of the same file - your terminal device.  So it should not be surprising that writing to `stdin` - or a `dup()` of `fileno(stdin)` - writes to your terminal device, and you see it.

If you run your program with `stdin` connected somewhere else, like a disk file, you'll see a different result:

```
./program < file
```

Comment: somewhere else means other than `stdout` ?? Can you please give me an example.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar: Somewhere else means somewhere other than your terminal, like a disk file.  I did give an example, where the `stdin` of `./program` is redirected to the file `file`.